# Simple vim function from visual mode to toggle comments (learning exercise)

Tags: vim

Partly for practice, and partly for personal use, I would like to be able to enter visual mode, select some lines, and then hit "," which would then toggle commenting. (I know NerdCommenter exists but I want something simple with nothing fancy - and again, this is practice, too.)

I've learned that you can do '&filetype' to access the filetype, and that '.' concatenates strings, ==# is case-sensitive string comparison, and =~ is regex matching. I also learned that getline('.') gets the line that visual mode has highlighted (each line if multiple lines are highlighted).

Here's my (flawed)

## .vimrc

```
vnoremap , :call ToggleComment()<CR>
function! ToggleComment()
  "Choose comment string based on filetype.
  let comment_string = ''
  if &filetype ==# 'vim'
    let comment_string = '"'
  elseif &filetype ==# 'cpp'
    let comment_string = '\/\/'
  endif

  let line = getline('.')
  if line =~ '^' . comment_string
    "Comment.
    " How could I do the equivalent of "shift-I to go to the beginning of the
    " line, then enter comment_string"?
  else
    "Uncomment. This is flawed too. Maybe I should just go to the beginning of
    "the line and delete a number of characters over?
    execute 's/^' . comment_string . '//'
  endif
endfunction
```

One thing I get for the uncomment case, regardless of whether the line is commented or not, is

```
Pattern not found: ^"
```

(I tested on my vimrc file.)

Advice appreciated - I feel like this shouldn't be too complicated.

Comment: As this is an exercise you may want to look into `:h 'commentstring'`. I would also suggest Tim Pope's commentary as a nice reference implementation. https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `range` option after function declatarion, that lets you use two variables that contain the beginning and end of the range, `a:firstline` and `a:lastline`.

Inside an `execute` instruction prepend them to the substitution command to executes it only in that range. At the time of removing apply `escape()` to the variable to avoid collision of forward slashes:

```
function! ToggleComment() range
    let comment_string = ''
    if &filetype ==# 'vim'
        let comment_string = '"' 
    elseif &filetype ==# 'cpp'
        let comment_string = '//'
    endif
    let line = getline('.')
    if line =~ '^' . comment_string
        execute a:firstline . "," . a:lastline . 's/^' . escape(comment_string, '/') . '//'
    else
        execute a:firstline . "," . a:lastline . 's/^/\=printf( "%s", comment_string )/'
    endif
endfunction
```

---

**UPDATE**: To add and remove comments just before first non-blank character, you have to add optional spaces after the zero-width assertion of beginning of line. This is the part that changes. Note how I add `\s*` to comparison if it exists comments in that line and add `\1` or `submatch(1)` in the replacement part of substitutions:

```
if line =~? '^\s*' . comment_string
    execute a:firstline . "," . a:lastline . 's/^\(\s*\)' . escape(comment_string, '/') . '/\1/'
else
    execute a:firstline . "," . a:lastline . 's/^\(\s*\)/\=submatch(1) . printf( "%s", comment_string )/'
endif
```

Comment: Okay I think I understand this. So you pass 'execute' the range, kind of like the line numbers when you do :12,14s/a/b to swap all a's to b's in lines 12 to 14. Cool. I also didn't know about the printf - thanks for that.

Comment: How would you make the comment symbol appear indented properly with each line? So if this was done on a single line, the comment string would appear indented 2x if the line of the code indented 2x?

Comment: @dmonopoly: Do you mean to insert comments just before first non-blank character of the line?

Comment: Yeah, just before the non-blank character, with a space between the [// or "] and the character...

Comment: This is great! But suppose we wanted comments like "// Hello", not just "//Hello". I have something I thought would work - I thought we would only need to change your uncomment line (the first 'execute' in your UPDATE section) to this: execute a:firstline . "," . a:lastline . 's/^\(\s*\)' . escape(comment_string, '/') . '\(\s*\)'  . '/\1\2/'   <-- The second capture group would catch any spaces between the // and the "Hello", and then we would add that to the replacement string, but this line seems to do the same as yours - it fails to delete the space between "//" and "Hello" in "// Hello".

Comment: @dmonopoly: You have to match optinal space after the comment character but not replace them, like this: `execute a:firstline . "," . a:lastline . 's/^\(\s*\)' . escape(comment_string, '/') . '\(\s*\)/\1/'`

Answer (score 0):

This probably fails, because your `:s` command doesn't find the comment string. You should probably use the `e` flag to your `:s` command (See also `:h s_flags`).

Additionally, I think you want to add a variable number of spaces between the line start and the comment string, e.g. something like `if line =~ '^\s*'.comment` so it does correctly catch:

```
#This is a comment
     #This is a comment
```

etc, you'll get the idea.